# How to remove the noise from a wav file with a IIR Eliptical filter

Tags: matlab, wav, noise-reduction

I have to remove the noise from a wav music file with matlab.

I know that I have to use the `ellipord` and `ellip` functions. First I read the wav file:`[x,Fs]=wavread('file.wav');`

Then I do a spectrogram: 
`spectrogram(x,512,400,512,Fs,'yaxis');`

[image]

Now, I can't understand some things:

- I have to remove that red line? (I suppose that's the noise)
- What is the Wp value on the ellipord function? (I know it calls passband corner frequency).
- The Ws value will be something like between 14000 and 16000 hz? It's value to remove the noise? How can I figure it out the values of Wp, Ws, Rs and Rp looking to this spectrogram?

Comment: There is a tone at 15 kHz - the long horizontal red line. If you're trying to remove it, you need a notch filter there. The stop band will be centered on 15 kHz and the passband will be everything above and below. Play with cutoff frequencies until you get acceptable tone removal without losing too much signal. Try listening to it! (`wavplay`)

Comment: So, I'll have 2 Wp's? Something like 0 to 14.9khz and another one 15.1khz to 20khz?

Comment: `ELLIP(N,Rp,Rs,Wp,'stop') is a bandstop filter if Wp = [W1 W2]`. Remember that frequencies are specified in terms of sampling frequency and should be in range 0 to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your noise looks like high frequency hiss at 15000 Hz. I think the best way to remove this noise is a bandstop filter, though it is hard to say without listening, maybe a lowpass filter will fit your requirements better. I'd try other filter types as well

```
Fs = 44100;
%what frequencies do you want to pass
wp = [12000 18000] / (Fs/2);
%what frequencies you don't want to pass
ws = [14000 16000] / (Fs/2);
%ellipsoid filter characteristics must be smooth
%so you have to select how many decibels 
%you allow to lose at passband (i.e. 12000 and 18000 hz)
rp = 3;
%stopband (minus decibels at 14000 and 16000 hz)
rs = 60;
[n,Wp] = ellipord(wp,ws,rp,rs)
[b,a] = ellip(n,rp,rs,wp,'stop');
freqz(b,a,Fs,Fs);
```

Comment: Why do you use 7 on the ellip and not the `n`? So, how can I get my `x` again to do a new spectrogram?

Comment: I was experimenting and missed that 7. You can experiment too to see how filter order (n) affects characteristics. After you have known `b` and `a` you can use `filter(b, a, x)` function to apply a filter

Comment: yes, I did it, it sounds good, and now I don't have so much noise, I think now I only have to play with the values to reach to the best 'clean' sound, right?

Comment: Yes. You can also try `fdatool` to learn more about filter types

Comment: if you use `wp = [14950 15050] / (Fs/2);` and `ws = [14990 15010] / (Fs/2);`it sounds perfect, so I'll accept your answer.